# two scrolling jquery tools plugin in a page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tools

i want to use both of these jquery tools plugin in a page:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/site-navigation.html

and

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/easing.html

but they conflict with each other.i mean when i scroll through the first one the second one also scroll.

how can i solve it?

Comment: could we see the code your using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how to use two is in the same site of flowplayer

http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/#features

the only thing that you need to do is put all the code in a div include in that the part of the next and prev button and that is all you can have alla the scrollable that you want and with CSS can change how it looks. :D

Comment: thanks,the solution in my case was not completely like that.i need to add next and prev button for site-navigation box,so it has its own buttons and doesn't take other scrolling instant button.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution is naming different "next", "prev" button classes.

for instance:

```
jQuery(".scrollable").scrollable({ next: '.scrollableTwoNext', prev: '.scrollableTwoPrev', easing: 'custom',speed: 700 });
```

This helped me when puting  didn't.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't using the same class for both of them, I notice they both use `.scrollable` in their examples. If you post your code it would help in answering though.

Example of what might work depending on your code.

```
$(".horScroll").scrollable({ circular: true }).navigator(".navi");

$(".easeScroll").scrollable({easing: 'custom', speed: 700, circular: true});
```

Notice they both are called something different.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on how the plugin was designed... if it is looking for an element with a unique ID (or it generates only 1 ID) then it won't handle multiple instances.

However if you are using it in 2 places, but using the same ID's more than once (invalid), that is something you will have to change. e.g. Just use 2 different ID's.

If you can add some sample code, we can help debug it.